# Where can I ask guidance-related questions about physics?

Tags: discussion

For example, I want to ask -
How is a physics question made difficult in competitive exams? I want to know this so as to overcome the hardness/fear of a question.

Where should I ask this question?

Comment: What is difficult for you may be easy for other students, and the other way around (that is, difficult for them but easy for you). I don’t think there is an objective criterion for difficulty. It depends on what you understand, how you think, etc.

Comment: With sufficient reputation, you can ask such questions in [chat]. On the main site, however, this would be off-topic.

Comment: There are "brute force" ways to make a question difficult -- for example, the solution might require evaluating a difficult integral. However, I think more elegant approaches are (a) "obscurity": taking a problem that you could solve easily if it was presented in the way that you are used to seeing, but modifying the statement of the problem so it is no longer obvious what tool(s) to apply, or (b) "synthesis": requiring you to combine two ideas, where you know the ideas separately, but haven't seen them put together in the way you need to solve the problem.